# Free or cheap tool for online dashboards and data visualization

Tags: data-visualization

I have a java swing application used to manage inventory, sales, cash flow, customers and other things of small business (generally newstands and similar business).

The application is offline, but I want to create in the website a dashboard where the users could see interesting charts and reports about its data. So probably I would create a mechanism in the offline application in order to be updating the database online day after day.

So my question is: does anyone know a good tool for developing dashboards? I don't need a complete BI tool because the users have 0% IT knowledge, I want something very simple, just like some graphics with different filters.

If possible I would prefer some free or cheap tools.

Thanks!!

Comment: You have already seen [D3](http://d3js.org/), haven't you?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information (especially on the requirements: must-haves, nice-to-haves, shoulds and should-nots) to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 3):

The data sounds small. So I would recommend embedding all data in a JSONP file called by an HTML/JavaScript page that uses Google Charts to render the data.

There will be a day of programming to convert the data to JSONP and write the charts, but it is very easy coding.

Then configure a daily task that generates the JSONP every and sends it to a web server via FTP. You can easily find free hosting for static HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: hmm sounds like a good idea..
I was thinking that maybe it can be done locally. Google charts are basically a html page with javascript, so I can add it to the appication and the user could just open it locally in his browser.